# Using a template in a different namespace

Tags: c++, templates, namespaces

I am not sure as to the exact problem, but this code:

```
template<class T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
    auto it(begin(vec));
    if (it != end(vec))
        ss << *(it++);
    for (; it != end(vec); ++it)
        ss << " " << *it;
    return ss;
}
```

gets picked up fine if it is in the same namespace as the place where I am trying to use it.

It doesn't get found if it is in a different one.

Why is that? Is there an easy fix? A `using`? A `::`?

Comment: ADL can't find it unless it's in `std`, which is illegal. Actually, it might already be illegal.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Not sure I understand you correctly, but when I place it in the global namespace, it still doesn't get found.

Comment: @Cookie, [Like this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bf06d85cf7926d4b)?

Comment: @Cookie: [Demo](http://ideone.com/1kECpJ)

Comment: @both of you: been reading around. Koenig lookup (If I got this right) looks in the namespace of where you call and of the arguments, nowhere else. Your two examples both work because main is in the global namespace.

Comment: @Cookie, The call to `operator<<` is inside of our created namespace. Where the function that makes this call is called from doesn't matter. What example do you have that doesn't work?

Comment: @chris: [Here is one](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/598a9579a0c81baf). Remove the using and it breaks.

Comment: [This](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/63747bd7a96923ce) (in a sense, the opposite of the two previous examples) doesn't work. Is something like this meant by "It doesn't get found if it is in a different one." ?

Comment: @Cookie, I present [this example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2955cabbe2d2f5e3), which is closer to my original (the parameter could have stayed a parameter; it doesn't matter). It already found `operator<<` in `foo`, so it doesn't search the surrounding namespaces for one. Then, out of the only one it finds there, and the ones from `std`, none match. The `using` statement you have brings the one in the global namespace into scope. As shown by [swapping them](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/418494fe185d57bc), it does not consider the one in `foo` after doing so for the same reason.

Comment: Ah that makes more sense!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [code](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/598a9579a0c81baf) you posted in a comment, I see the following solution:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

template<class T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
    auto it(begin(vec));
    if (it != end(vec))
        ss << *(it++);
    for (; it != end(vec); ++it)
        ss << " " << *it;
    return ss;
}

namespace foo {
    struct MyClass
    {
        std::vector<int> m_vec;
    };
    using ::operator<<;
    inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, MyClass const& in)
    {
      return ss << "ClassVec: " << in.m_vec;
    }
}

int main() {
    foo::MyClass test;
    test.m_vec = {1,2,3};
    std::cout << test;
}
```

That is, there's a

```
using ::operator<<;
```

within `namespace foo`. The reason is that your

```
std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, MyClass const& in)
```

within `namespace foo` is *hiding* `::operator<<`. By `using` it explicitly, the two `operator<<` (the global and the `foo::` one) are now *overloaded*, so both are available.

This way, you can define as many `operator<<` as you like within `foo::`, and the global one will still be available.

Answer (score 0):

Two solutions:

```
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, MyClass const& in)
{
  using ::operator<<;
  return ss << "ClassVec: " << in.m_vec;
}
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, MyClass const& in)
{ 
  ss << "ClassVec: ";
  ::operator<<(ss, in.m_vec);
  return ss;
}
```

With this, my `include_vector.h` becomes:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( push )
#pragma warning (disable : 4996)
#endif

#include <vector>

typedef std::vector<double> DoubleVector;

template<class T>
inline std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& ss, std::vector<T> const& vec)
{
  auto it(begin(vec));
  if (it != end(vec))
    ss << *(it++);
  for (; it != end(vec); ++it)
    ss << " " << *it;
  return ss;
}

#ifdef _MSC_VER
#pragma warning( pop )
#endif
```

Comment: Optionally add `using ::operator<<;` to the bottom, depends on your code base I guess

Comment: An incomplete answer to your own incomplete question?

Comment: Should I not have answered? What is missing?

Comment: From the question, you were missing a complete code to reproduce the problem, so three people had to guess. A complete code followed only in a link within a comment. For the answer, you are still missing that the two "solutions" are not in a namespace, and there is no test case.